# PHP 2 get methods

Tags: php, get

How do i do 2 get methods in php where it will check the id of the two. And how will i run it in my browser? Example
localhost/aaa/bbb/Get.php?s_id=1 how will i add the next id in the browser?

Here is my php code

```
$s_id = $_GET['s_id'];
$m_id = $_GET['m_id'];
 require_once('db.php');

 $sql = "select * from matches a inner join sport b on a.s_id = b.s_id where s_id = $s_id and m_id = $m_id ORDER by m_no ASC";


 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 $result = array();


 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

 array_push($result,array(
 "s_id"=>$row['s_id'],
 "m_id"=>$row['m_id'],
 "teamone"=>$row['teamone'],
 "teamtwo"=>$row['teamtwo'],
"teamonepts"=>$row['teamonepts'],
"teamtwopts"=>$row['teamtwopts'],
"s_gender"=>$row['s_gender'],
"s_name"=>$row['s_name']
 ));
 }

 echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
```

I am getting this response

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\atfest\cpanel\mobile\GetSports1.php on line 15
{"result":[]}
```

Comment: Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
while ($row = $r->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 array_push($result,array(
 "s_id"=>$row['s_id'],
 "m_id"=>$row['m_id'],
 "teamone"=>$row['teamone'],
 "teamtwo"=>$row['teamtwo'],
 "teamonepts"=>$row['teamonepts'],
 "teamtwopts"=>$row['teamtwopts'],
 "s_gender"=>$row['s_gender'],
"s_name"=>$row['s_name']
 ));
 }
```

Replace this snippet in your code,

Give it a try.

**EDIT**

in your case give try to this,

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ // }
```

There is one more way,

```
while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){ // }
```

similar classical way

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){ // }
```

Comment: Mate, you have lots of options to try, try one by one.

Comment: all have the same problem sir, the thing is i am new to php and i dont know these functions sir

Comment: I don't think you are getting same error on every single attempts

Comment: Other choices you posted gives me this sir. Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: and this     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?

Comment: gives me this mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135048/discussion-between-rahul-m-and-osoda).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `Get.php` function expects both `s_id` and `m_id` parameters. To supply these parameters, you should put `&` in between them like in this example below:

```
localhost/aaa/bbb/Get.php?s_id=1&m_id=2
```

Answer (score 0):

//Write this code at the end of your form

```
    var s_id = $("#s_id").val();//id of your text input of s_id
    var m_id = $("#m_id").val();//id of your text input of m_id
    $.ajax({
      url: "Get.php",
      type:'POST',
      data:"s_id="+s_id+"m_id="+m_id,
    }).done(function() {

        alert("Success");

    });
```

Then in your Get.php you can able to get the

```
     $s_id = $_POST['s_id'];
     $m_id = $_POST['m_id'];
```